QGIS getting the height from a *.gml file
So national geoportal is providing me with vector buildings in a GML file.
They import great to the QGIS. but the atribiutes table does not have usual height field.

In a 3d view they are flat.  But for sure data is 3d with height as if I do the 3d exporter plugin it display they heights properly

But I need and shp export with normal height atribute field, How do I recover it from the GML. As for now the shp exports as flat files no 3d.

Default menu: Vector ► Geometry Tools add geometry attributes.
